# Using NGINX server, Internet Explorer/Google Search Console shows gibberish

Tags: internet-explorer, nginx, mediawiki

I'm running a Mediawiki with short URL configuration (example.com/Page_Title)

```
location ~ \.htaccess {
    deny all;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php;
}

location ^~ /maintenance/ {
    return 403;
}

location ^~ /cache/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
```

Chrome and Firefox renders it just fine, but why does it show as gibberish on IE or Google Search Console like this: �~����=�r۶����� and so on. Running a test .html or .php looks fine, only rewritten Mediawiki pages are showing gibberish.

The content-type and charset from HTTP response header seems to be correct:

```
Response Headers
cache-control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-encoding: gzip, gzip
content-language: en
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 23 May 2016 11:32:39 GMT
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
last-modified: Mon, 23 May 2016 11:02:34 GMT
server: nginx
vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff, nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by: HHVM/3.11.1
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge, IE=Edge
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be coming from multiple attempt to gzip the content, hence the double gzip in http header.

```
content-encoding: gzip, gzip
```

Adding this parameter in nginx config solved the issue.

```
fastcgi_param   HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING "";
```